# How to pass file into PHP CLI?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script named "scipt" and a textfile called 'data.txt'. Right now I can execute script, but then I need to type in "data.txt". Is there any way to pass in data.txt as a parameter to "script" so I can run this thing in one line automated?

Right now I'm typing:

```
php script {enter} // script runs and waits for me to type filename
data.txt {enter}
... executes
```

Ideally it would look like:

```
php script data.txt {enter}
...executes
```

I'm doing this all from the PHP command line. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 mscharley@S04:~$ cat test.php
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER['argc']);
var_dump($_SERVER['argv']);
?>
 mscharley@S04:~$ php test.php foo bar
int(3)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "test.php"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
 mscharley@S04:~$
```

Comment: assuming the next step is file_get_contents...is `file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$argv[1]);` the way to go? does it look in it's own directory by default (so `file_get_contents($argv[1]);` would be enough?) I don't have a command line version available, but need to build something that will be accessed that way. Thanks so much

Comment: nevermind...it's working now as I expected, something else must have been the problem

Answer (score 1):

Arguments to your script will be available in [$argv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Answer (score 0):

Or `$_SERVER['argv']` (which doesn't require `register_globals` being turned on) - however, both solutions DO require having `register_argc_argv` turned on. See [the documentation](http://php.net/ini.list) for details.

Comment: From the command line, argv/argc are available regardless of register_argc_argv, since 4.3.0.  See: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: That's not 100% true. That's merely the DEFAULT value compiled into the SAPI - this can be overridden via php.ini or command-line arguments. e.g.:

/tmp $ cat x
<?php var_dump($_SERVER['argv']);

/tmp $ php -d register_argc_argv=0 -f x a b c
NULL

Also, it assumes that the CLI SAPI is in use, rather than the CGI SAPI (it's quite common to find people using the CGI SAPI as a 'CLI' solution due to distro preferences for paths)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need the file, you can get the file name by using the [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) variable. That would allow you to run it like

```
php script data.txt
```

Then "data.txt" will be $argv[1](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) ($argv[0] is the script name itself).

If you don't actually need the file, but only its content. You can process standard input (STDIN) using any of the normal stream reading functions ([stream_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php), [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) etc...). This allows you to direct standard input like so:

```
php script << data.txt
```

This is a common paradigm for *nix-style utilities.